# The grammatical function of "-en" in "aus dem Französischen, Englischen" etc.

Tags: translation, grammatical-case, sentence-structure

In the German phrase "aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche übersetzen", the language name, which is neutral in German, ends with "-en" after "aus dem", while after "ins" it ends in an "-e". Can anyone explain that?

How are these sentences translated into German:

> I want to talk to her in German (English)
>   I wanted to write this message to you in German (or English)
>   She always speaks to me in German (English)

I am focusing on languages other than *Deutsch* because maybe it's a *substantiviertes Adjektiv*.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but it's "aus dem Deutschen" because aus is a dative preposition and so "Deutsch-" is in the dative and it's "ins Englische" because in is being used there as an accusative preposition "into English" so "Englisch-" is accusative. Also, your sentences don't fit well with the question you're asking. You talk, write etc. "auf Deutsch" or "in der deutschen Sprache" but translate "ins Deutsche" or "aus dem Deutschen"

Comment: Random sentences in the middle od a question tend to confuse people. Soooo. Why are there these three sentences, which have no obvious connection to the question??

Comment: @thekeyofgb "ins Englische" I know it's in akkusative case but why it ends with "-e" bcz it's in nominative case "Das Englisch" also the same for e.g. "aus dem Englischen" in dative, why it ends with "-en" ... plz if u can explain more...

Comment: @Vogel612 second part of my question, is what we use after "schreiben" auf/zu/in Englisch or any language else... same thing, after "sprechen"

Comment: The language names are being used as adjectival nouns.  Those are adjective endings.

Comment: @Khaled that was not clear to me. Also, as you maybe know, pure translation requests are discouraged. please try to reformulate your question with german examples ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 "Ich schrieb an ihn den Brief auf Spanisch"   "Ich will mit ihm auf Französisch sprechen"   "Dein Name bedeutet in Schottisch ..." Do these three sentences are right? are the prepositions are the correspondant prepositions in these sentences?

Comment: “Das Deutsche” means “die deutsche Sprache” in contexts like these. I do not know much about formal grammar, but I would think that as you suggested (and @thekeyofgb confirmed) these are “substantivierte Adjektive”. The rest is normal conjugation, “aus *Dativ* in *Akkusativ*”.

Comment: @Khaled this is a question to ask in Chat. Also you should not make amendments to a question in comments. Your first sentence should use *"ihm"* instead of *"an ihn"*. Your second sentence is alright that way, even though you can also leave out the *"auf"*. Your third sentence is a bit tricky, I don't know the correct Form myself

Comment: @Vogel612 thanks a lot, but the third sentence I wrote "Dein Name bedeutet in Schottisch" if it's not true, can it be replaced with "zu Schottisch, dein Name lautet etwas..."?!!

Comment: @Khaled that will not work..  also i just said i don't know if it actually is correct, because it damn well may be

Answer (score 2):

It's a contraction of sorts of the expression *übersetzt/übertragen aus der französischen Sprache*, which eventually became *aus dem Französischen* (*die französische Sprache* having been contracted into *das Französische*). Constructions like this are called adjectival nouns, and are an odd combination of syntax and linguistic logic. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] ends with "-en" after "aus dem", while after "ins" it ends in an "-e". Can anyone explain that?

Have a look at this table from [wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Deutsch):

```
case      - declension (sing. 2)
--------------------------------
Nominativ - das Deutsche    
Genitiv   - des Deutschen   
Dativ     - dem Deutschen   
Akkusativ - das Deutsche
```

Thus it's `in das Deutsche` (<strike>Nom.</strike> Akk.) and `aus dem Deutschen` (Dat.)

Further `in das Deutsche` becomes `ins Deutsche`

and in spoken language `aus dem Deutschen` often becomes `aus'm Deutschen`

Answer (score 0):

embert gave you the best hint about it, but made a mistake:
"in das Deutsche" is an Akkusativ (accusative), not a Nominativ (nominative). For fem. and neutr. nouns the rule is that Nominativ and Akkusativ are the same form with the same article (die Frau [Nom], die Frau [Akk], das Haus [Nom], das Haus [Akk])

The preposition "in" can have two cases:
in + Dativ (dative) describes a location: "Ich bin in der Schule" (I am at school).
in + Akkusativ describes a direction: "Ich gehe in den Wald" (I'm going/ I go to the forest)

in + das is often shortened to "ins", likewise "in + dem" to "im".

"aus" requires a Dativ which is "Englischen" when it comes to the English language. Therefore "aus dem Englischen" has this form due to being the Dativ of "das Englisch". The article "dem" gives you a hint.

Source:

I'm a native German speaker ;)